# How to show that $ord_n(x)=lcm(ord_p(x), ord_q(x))$ for primes p,q such that $n=pq$

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to show

$ord_n(x)=lcm(ord_p(x), ord_q(x))$ for primes p,q such that $n=pq$

I tried a few different things and found some similar questions but I failed to understand them. Please help me?

I thought of simply using the definition of ord and lcm and their commutative properties to prove it but I get $lcm(\text{ord}_p(x),\text{ord}_q(x))|\text{ord}_n(x)$ and not sure how this would prove the above.

Another proof that I fail to understand:

This follows because $x^j \equiv 1 (mod n) \iff x^j \equiv 1 mod p$ and $x^j \equiv 1 mod q$ but it is not immediately obvious why that is the case. Because the above is the definition of order

Similar questions I read but failed to understand:

[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2898860/what-is-the-multiplicative-order-of-a-product-of-two-integers-mod-n)

[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1576800/prove-that-lcma-b-prod-i-1-p-i-max-alpha-i-beta-i)

[3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147567/prove-that-the-order-of-an-element-in-the-group-n-is-the-lcmorder-of-the-elemen)

[Lema 1.7](https://math.hawaii.edu/%7Eallan/AdditionalGroupTheory.pdf)

Comment: The last proof you say you don’t understand is just the Chinese Remainder Theorem, which I think is the most straightforward way of showing what you want.

Comment: Can you expand please. How is that the case? i.e. I get why the statements are true but I do not see how they connect to LCM

Comment: @user2789433 Use that if $a|c$ and $b|c$ then $lcm(a,b)|c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that
$$x^k\equiv 1\pmod{n}\implies x^k\equiv 1\pmod{pq}\implies x^k\equiv 1\pmod{p}, 1\pmod{q}$$
By the Chinese Remainder Theorem (since $p,q$ are relatively prime). Thus, by basic properties of the order, $ord_p(x), ord_q(x)|k\implies lcm(ord_p(x), ord_q(x))|k$ by the definition of lcm. Hence it suffices to show that $k=lcm(ord_p(x), ord_q(x))$ is a solution to $x^k\equiv 1\pmod{pq}$. This is true because $x^k\equiv 1\pmod{p}, 1\pmod{q}$, and the result follows by the chinese remainder theorem.